# architectural questions for .net connexion to DB

Tags: .net

in my project i'm working whith sqlServer db and it's work fine  but i need to get somme informations from orable db (second part of my db in oracle) 
my question is : 
should i create a new connexion to oracle or using a web service to get this informations from oracle db.

tnks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Repository pattern with EF and create a DbContext for both using either built-in or open source providers or use commercial ones like from
www.devart.com so your application is DB agnostic.

You can also try linked server:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2013/10/02/creating-a-linked-server-for-oracle-in-64bit-sql-server.aspx

Here you can just use the sql server and the sql server connects to oracle.

Comment: So i will create a second dbContext for my oracle db  by using the repository pattern tnks for your helping